# Why does orthogonalizing the monomials give Legendre polynomials?

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

It's pretty well known that performing a Gram-Schmidt process on the monomials,

$$
p_j(x) = x^j - \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \frac{\langle x^j|p_i\rangle}{\langle p_i|p_i \rangle}p_i(x),
$$

gives (scaled) Legendre polynomials when $p_0(x) = 1$, $p_1(x) = x$, and

$$
\langle f | g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \,g(x) \;\mathrm{d}x.
$$

However, $p_0(x) = 1$ and $p_1(x) = x$ are *also* the first two Chebyshev polynomials which have the same orthogonality and completeness properties that the Legendre polynomials do. Why, then, is the Gram-Schmidt process "biased" to generate Legendre polynomials instead of Chebyshev ones, and does this suggest Legendre and Chebyshev polynomials are in some sense the "same" when interpreted correctly?

Comment: Aha. I see now. That was clever. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing here is that "same orthogonality and completeness as ... does".

Orthogonality here always relates to some specified inner product. The main difference as far as I can see is in the definition of inner product for which these families of polynomials are designed. Those are *different* inner products.

You are renormalizing using the inner product for which the Legendre polynomials are designed to be orthogonal for:

$$\left<f|g\right> = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x)  {dx}$$

Try changing your renormalizing scalar product to:

$$\left<f|g\right> = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) \cdot \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

It is the factor $\frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ which supposedly makes big difference in results.

I would not be surprised if the new choice would generate Chebyshev polynomials if you keep everything else the same in the Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Comment: Oh, right! Of course the Chebyshev polynomials have a different inner product; this is why I shouldn't SO in the morning. Making that change does, indeed, recover the Chebyshev polynomials exactly. Thanks!